# Why synchronous task don't free memory after complete

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I need convert 5.000.000 records from DB to JSON, but I'm running out of memory after 4.000 records.

I'm using Task thinking when the task is complete the GC clear everything in the thread from memory.

```cs
public class Program()
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.ExportUsingTask();
    }

    public void ExportUsingTask()
    {
        List<int> ids = Program.LoadID(); // trying dont keep DBContext references, so GC can free memory
        GC.Collect(); // GC can clear 130MB of memory, DBContext have no references anymore
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        foreach (int item in ids)
        {
            Task job = new Task(() => new Program().Process(item));
            job.RunSynchronously();
            Task.WaitAll(job);
            job.Dispose();
            job = null;
            GC.Collect(); // GC don't clear memory, uses more and more memory at each iteration, until OutOfMemoryException
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }

    public static List<int> LoadID()
    {
        List<int> ids = new List<int>();
        using (Context db = new Context())
        {
            ids = db.Alfa.Where(a => a.date.Year == 2019).Select(a => a.id).ToList<int>(); // load 500.000 id from DB, use 130MB of memory
            // have some business logic here, but isn't the problem, memory is free after execution anyway
            db.Dispose();
        }

        return ids;
    }

    public void Process(int id)
    {
        Beta b = GetBetaFromAlfa(id); // Beta is JSON model that I need save to file
        string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b);
        b = null;

        using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"c:\MyFile.json"))
        {
            sw.Write(json);
            sw.Close();
            sw.Dispose();
        }

        GC.Collect(); // GC don't clear memory
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }

    public static Beta GetBetaFromAlfa(int idAlfa)
    {
        Alfa a = null; // Alfa is my model in DB
        Beta b = null; // Beta is JSON model that I need save to file

        using (Context db = new Context())
        {
            Alfa a = db.Alfa.Single(a => a.id == idAlfa); 
            b = ConvertAlfaToBeta(a);
            db.Dispose();
        }

        GC.Collect(); // GC don't clear memory
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        return b;
    }

    public static Beta ConvertAlfaToBeta(Alfa alfa)
    {
        // business logic, something like:
        // beta.id = alfa.id;
        // beta.name = alfa.name;
        // only simple type association (int, string, decimal, datetime, etc)
    }
}

public class Alfa(){ ... }
public class Beta(){ ... }
```

In the first try, I did a single loop reading records one by one, when I got 100 records, I saved all JSON to file. But I ran out of memory anyway when I got 4000 records, using loop:

```cs
    public void ExportUsingLoop()
    {
        List<int> ids = Program.LoadID(); // trying dont keep DBContext references, so GC can free memory
        GC.Collect(); // GC can clear 130MB of memory, DBContext have no references anymore
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        int count = 0;
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (int item in ids)
        {
            count++;
            Beta b = GetBetaFromAlfa(id); // Beta is JSON model that I need save to file
            string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b);
            content.AppendLine(json);

            b = null;
            json = null;

            if(count % 100 == 0)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"c:\MyFile.json"))
                {
                    sw.Write(content.ToString());
                    content.Clear(); // just for clarification
                    sw.Close();
                    sw.Dispose();
                }

                GC.Collect(); // GC don't clear memory, uses more and more memory at each iteration, until OutOfMemoryException
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you are getting an "OutOfMemoryException" because of your string builder, not anything else. Try writing directly to a file instead of sticking everything in memory, and take all the `GC.xxx` calls out and let GC work how it is designed.

Comment: You also don't have to call `db.Dispose` if you are using the context inside a `using` statement. The `using` will dispose of the object for you. Same for `sw.Dispose()` for stream writers.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to clear the contents of the StringBuilder after writing to the file?

Comment: @RonBeyer StringBuilder is inside foreach, but I don't use it anymore, now I'm using Task and write records one by one

Comment: Your `ids` list shouldn't take more than ~2 MB... I'm pretty sure you got something else going in the background. Any chance you could get a heap snapshot?

Comment: @mostanes when I load ids, DBContex uses 130MB: `List<int> ids = Program.LoadID(); GC.Collect();` but the GC frees memory, when I call GC.Collect(), I'll  upload the memory usage print screen from Visual Studio

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of dumping the objects in the managed heaps, rather than simply the memory used by the process (something along the lines of dotMemory). Anyway, try bisecting the problem. What happens if you don't append `json` to `content` or not compute `json`, etc.?

Comment: It would be great if you provided real code. Lines line `public class Program()` and `public class Alfa()` are not valid. Why post code that's not compilable?

Comment: @mostanes bisecting the problem was the solutuon. the problem was the code `Beta b = ConvertAlfaToBeta(alfa);` it's integrate with ADABAS using XmlSerializer. Code from 2011 and never reviewed.